# git push в два репозитория в gitlab github

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Мне нужно проект и изменения пушать в два репозитория в Gitlab и Github.

Для начала я связала свой локальный с github "

```
git remote add origin url репозитория
```

Затем я пыталась то же самое проделать с gitlab. Сгенерировала и добавила SSH key в gitlab и написала:

```
git remote add origin url репозитория
```

В git bash пишет ошибку `error: remote origin already exists.`, при проверке

```
git remote -v
```

показывает только url гитхаба.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как связать проект с репо гитлаба и как потом пушать изменения в два репозитория.

Спасибо!

Comment: Называйте второй remote не origin, а по-другому

Answer (score 2, accepted):

origin в гите - это не ключевое слово, а назначаемое вами же условное имя для удалённого репозитория. Вы не можете использовать одно имя для обоих репозиториев, но зато можете использовать любые имена какие удобны вам.

Например, можно сделать так:

```
git remote add github url_репозитория
git remote add gitlab url_репозитория
```

Пушить после этого можно с указанием имени удалённого репозитория:

```
git push github
git push gitlab
```

Но, если вам требуется всего лишь зеркало для репозитория, возможно вам больше подойдёт функция [Repository mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/) из гитлаба.